# ScalaTest HTML report using Eclipse plugin

Tags: html, eclipse, plugins, report, scalatest

Is there any option, how to make ScalaTest reporting into HTML file using Eclipse ScalaTest plugin?

In Run configuration I setted Program argment to:

```
-h C:\Users\medek\Scala
```

but it wrotes:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort. This may have been caused by a problematic custom reporter.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pegdown/PegDownProcessor
at org.scalatest.tools.HtmlReporter.<init>(HtmlReporter.scala:115)
at org.scalatest.tools.ReporterFactory.createHtmlReporter(ReporterFactory.scala:182)
at org.scalatest.tools.ReporterFactory.getReporterFromConfiguration(ReporterFactory.scala:233)
at org.scalatest.tools.ReporterFactory$$anonfun$createReportersFromConfigurations$1.apply(ReporterFactory.scala:242)
at org.scalatest.tools.ReporterFactory$$anonfun$createReportersFromConfigurations$1.apply(ReporterFactory.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at org.scalatest.tools.ReporterConfigurations.foreach(ReporterConfiguration.scala:43)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at org.scalatest.tools.ReporterConfigurations.map(ReporterConfiguration.scala:43)
at org.scalatest.tools.ReporterFactory.createReportersFromConfigurations(ReporterFactory.scala:241)
at org.scalatest.tools.ReporterFactory.getDispatchReporter(ReporterFactory.scala:245)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2720)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:860)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher$.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala:58)
at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pegdown.PegDownProcessor
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 25 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added all needed dependencies and it works - but - I dont think that this is correct behaviour.

Dependencies:

- pegdown-1.1.0.jar
- parboiled-core-1.0.2.jar
- parboiled-java-1.0.2.jar
- asm-all-3.3.1.jar

Comment: I only needed the first one.